# How to push data twice into object

Tags: javascript

Is there any possible to push some data into an object twice and get one result? I have this code:

```
var t = data.datasets,

var data = {
    datasets : (function(){
        var arr = [];
        for (var i=0; i < t.length; i++) {
            arr.push({
                label: t[i].label,
                data: t[i].values
            });
            if (t[i].color === "red"){
                arr.push({
                    fillColor: "rgba(223, 34, 155, 0.48)"
                });
            } else {
                arr.push({
                    fillColor: "rgba(167, 167, 167, 0.64)"
                });
            }
        }
        return arr;
    })()
};
```

on the and i need this:

```
arr.push({
    label: t[i].label,
    data: t[i].values,
    fillColor: "rgba(167, 167, 167, 0.64)" // or other
});
```

Or I must push this repetitive values include on each condition?

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand, unfortunately. Also, your code won't work if that's really what it looks like - the code initializes "t" *before* it defines the "data" object, so "t" will be `undefined` at best, or it'll throw an exception because "data" is also `undefined`.

Comment: don't understand what exactly you want to do. you want to insert different values in your JSON based on some condition?

Comment: just push the entire object in one time

Comment: Also, this isn't a JSON. This is just an ordinary Javascript object.

Comment: What is wrong and not clear in this question and why other people understands that? Why -4 votes?

Comment: @Lukas: People answering your question are doing by reading between the lines. You question, as you stated it, is very confusing. The code you posted, as Pointy mentioned, won't even run as is and it's very unclear what "push data twice" is supposed to mean.

Comment: OK, but i think that push is push, and in code it's only one method with this name ... sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something like this:

```
    for (var i=0; i < t.length; i++) {
        var temp = {
            label: t[i].label,
            data: t[i].values
        };
        if (t[i].color === "red"){
            temp.fillColor = "rgba(223, 34, 155, 0.48)";
        } else {
            temp.fillColor: = "rgba(167, 167, 167, 0.64)";
        }
        arr.push(temp);
    }
```

That way you don't have to keep repeating the `label` and `data` part.

Or, if you only have two possible values for `fillColor` (you could do more, but it'll quickly get to be a mess), you could do this:

```
arr.push({
      label: t[i].label,
      data: t[i].values,
      fillColor: t[i].color === "red" ? "rgba(223, 34, 155, 0.48)" : "rgba(167, 167, 167, 0.64)"
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

So, something like this?

```
        for (var i=0; i < t.length; i++) {
            var fillColor = t[i].color === 'red' ? 
                "rgba(223, 34, 155, 0.48)" : 
                "rgba(167, 167, 167, 0.64)";
            arr.push({
                label: t[i].label,
                data: t[i].values,
                fillColor: fillColor
            });
        }
```

This still does not answer the concerns [raised by Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365808/how-to-push-data-twice-into-json-object#comment39552271_25365808), but I don't understand enough of what you're trying to do to give you any advice on that point.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest building a 'holder' variable, and then push that once.

pseudo code,

```
var holder = data;
if(a)
  holder+=moredata;
else
 holder+=otherdata;
```

then perform the single push

```
arr.push(holder);
```